# Multiplication of data from MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to be able to multiply all the prices for example from my database then multiply the total by 10.

The code below do the addition not multiplication

```
<?php
$d = $_GET['d'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);//

$sql= "SELECT SUM(prices) FROM tablename WHERE Date = '$d' AND Prices >0.20 AND Type= 'sold'";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
echo $row[0]*10;


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

example

```
id prices
1   25
2   36
3   45
```

That is i want 25*36*45*10 and not 25+36+45*10

Hope anyone can help

Comment: SELECT 4 * 5 AS 'test' or SELECT col1 * col2 AS 'test'

Comment: Also, for security, you need to escape your variable $d to prevent sql injection. `$d = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['d']);`

Comment: mysql does not have array_product

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work, with restrictions (numbers should be only positive):

```
SELECT 10 * EXP(SUM(LOG(prices))) AS result
FROM tablename 
WHERE ...
```

The thnx should go to **[`Napier`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Napier)** and his wonderful invention, **[`logarithms`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)**

Comment: Use `ROUND(X,2)`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same thing.  Too bad MySql doesn't have a PRODUCT() function.

Answer (score -1):

How does it not do the multiplication? You get `0`? You get an error?

You could do it within the database as is, remember that

```
10 x (a + b + c + ...)
```

is exactly the same as

```
10a + 10b + 10c + ...
```

So you could simply do

```
SELECT 10*SUM(prices) from ...
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(10*prices) from ...
```

However, I notice that you have NO error handling whatsoever. If your query fails, mysql_query() will return a boolean false, from which you then try to fetch a row, which would also return a boolean false.

that boolean false would then be in $row, and you use it as an array, meaning that $row[0] will be a php NULL. `NULL * 10`  would be integer 0.

Change your query call to be the following:

```
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

and see what pops up.

Comment: The OP isn't looking to calculate 10(a+b+c), but rather 10abc. I think they wan't a GROUP function along the lines of PRODUCT() rather than SUM().  But, unfortunately that doesn't exist.