# Multiplying across row in a query

Tags: sql-server

I have rows in table that i want to multiply all the values by itselft, but can't figure out how to make it work.

```
SELECT exp(bet_odd) as odds
FROM betting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(bet_odd))) as odds
FROM betting
```

Src:
[Multiplication of data from MySQL row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539104/multiplication-of-data-from-mysql-row) :

Comment: With the code the values multiplies against itself. for example a column has a value of 4. This code multiplies the 4 by itself to make it 16. What i want its to multiply all the values in the row. For instance first row has a value of 8, second row has a value of 6 and third a value of 6. I want these values to multiply by itself

Comment: @blay: you are welcome although the main credit goes to the original writer. I am learning also :)