# How to multiply value from one column in one table from database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to multiply value from table after I selected from database in one column and table using `forearch` loops

Here is my selection data from database and I don't know to multiply total value in its column

```
public function total_comp_in(){

        $this->query = $this->db->get_where('prifix',array('status'=>1)); 
        if($this->query->num_rows()>0){ 
             return $this->query->result();
        }
    }
```

the result I want to total my value as below images.

[image]

Comment: how exactly this multiplication results 48 and not 80?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiplication of data from MySQL row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539104/multiplication-of-data-from-mysql-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over the results and multiply it:

```
if($this->query->num_rows()>0){ 
    $total = 1;
    $result =  $this->query->result();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $total *= $row->total;
    } 
    return $total;
}
```

However, that won't make 2*2*2*2*5 equal 48... maybe if there was a 3 instead of that 5...

Comment: No problem, I tried to make a joke there. But that's the code that should work for you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one , you can get the result directly without looping (numbers should be only positive)

```
SELECT CAST(EXP(SUM(LOG(total))) AS UNSIGNED) AS result
FROM prifix WHERE status = 1
```

Comment: It is possible if I have 200 00 rows to calculate all time?
This app is used to calculate Accountant invoice if amount of rows increase up to 200 00 rows it will make total wrong or not?

Comment: This is great, an upvote from me! Actually, then I saw where you borrowed it from.

Comment: @Shomz,
It is possible or it might going wrong or errors or not if my rows will increase to 200 00 rows of that table?

Comment: The number of rows doesn't matter here, you should worry how large will the number get and thus what type should it be. Try predicting the worst-case scenario.

Comment: I create table prifix type: varchar(20) but when user input I used javascript to validate number only (exp:1,2,3 or 1.5 or 3.7) and result of total it will be able by amount of total number