# Get product of mysql array by ID

Tags: php, mysql

I need help to find the product of an mysql array sorted in groups.
So what I need is 1.2*1.5, and 1.1*1.6. And store them into some variables.

```
----------------
|Group_ID|Value|
----------------
|   1    | 1.2 |
----------------
|   1    | 1.5 |
----------------
|   2    | 1.1 |
----------------
|   2    | 1.6 |
----------------
```

Comment: That modeling of your data is not good. Why did you chose to create your table that way?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539104/multiplication-of-data-from-mysql-row

Comment: SELECT (MIN(Value)*MAX(Value))as prod FROM table_name GROUP BY Group_ID

Answer (score 0):

Has said above by Mat, your datamodel is not good, you have two choices :

- Alter your datamodel to be able to do all calculations using the SGBD (this is the better choice)
- Fetch your data and process them to the application side (may be slow if you're not familiar with code tuning and algorithm)

Edit : if your groups are always composed of two rows you can use the solution just above